# Convex Quadrilateral: $ \dfrac {\tan A + \tan B + \tan C + \tan D}{\tan A \tan B \tan C \tan D} = \cot A + \cot B + \cot C + \cot D $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math

**Problem**

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with no right angles. Show that $$ \dfrac {\tan A + \tan B + \tan C + \tan D}{\tan A \tan B \tan C \tan D} = \cot A + \cot B + \cot C + \cot D. $$

*Source*: [Geometry Unbound by *Kiran Kedlaya*](http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~mbasic/gu-060118.pdf).

**Attempt**: Well, all we really know about a convex quadrilateral are that $ \angle A + \angle B + \angle C + \angle D = 360^\circ $ and that the polygon is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon). Well, that's obvious. But any starts to a proof of this useful fact would be helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply the original identity by $\tan A \tan B \tan C \tan D$
$$
\tan A + \tan B + \tan C + \tan D = \tan B \tan C \tan D + \tan A \tan C \tan D + \tan A \tan B \tan D + \tan A \tan B \tan C.
$$
then find $\tan D$ from it 
$$
\tan D = \frac{\tan A \tan B \tan C - \tan A - \tan B - \tan C}{1 - \tan B \tan C - \tan A \tan C - \tan A \tan B}.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\tan D=\tan(2\pi -A - B - C)=-\tan(A + B + C)
$$
So it is remains to show that
$$
\tan(A + B + C)=\frac{\tan A + \tan B + \tan C - \tan A \tan B \tan C}{1 - \tan B \tan C - \tan A \tan C - \tan A \tan B}
$$
which was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177640/prove-tanaby-frac-tan-a-tan-b-tan-y-tan-a-tan-b-tan-y1-tan-a-tan).

Comment: Brilliant! $\mathrm{}$

Answer (score 2):

$$A+B+C+D=2\pi\iff A+B=2\pi-(C+D)$$

$$\implies\tan(A+B)=\tan\{2\pi-(C+D)\}=-\tan(C+D)$$

Using [Addition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) formula, $$\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}=-\frac{\tan C+\tan D}{1-\tan C\tan D}$$

On rearrangement, $$\sum \tan A=\sum \tan A\tan B\tan C=\prod\tan A\left(\sum\frac1{\tan A}\right)$$

$$\sum \tan A=\left(\prod\tan A\right)\left(\sum\cot A\right)$$

Divide either sides by $\prod\tan A$ which is non-zero and finite as no angle is multiple of $\displaystyle\frac\pi2$

Interestingly,  $\displaystyle A+B+C+D=n\pi$ (where $n$ is any integer) will satisfy this relation

Comment: @AhaanRungta, how about this one?

Comment: Also very nice! Unfortunately, I cannot accept more than one answer. :(

Comment: @AhaanRungta, acceptance is your call. I just wanted share an answer which needs lesser formula & calculations.

Comment: It is indeed nice, which is why I gave the +1. :)

Comment: @AhaanRungta, thanks for your feedback & also for the question

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the answer! :)