# Tan inverse summation

Tags: trigonometry, summation, inverse

$$S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{4}\tan^{-1} x_i$$

How to simplify this ?

I think I will have to use this :

[image: formula]

but it looks too long a method .

Is there a method or symmetrical way which yields the answer quickly ?

note : $x_i$ are the roots of a fourth degree polynomial so I know the sum and product of the roots

Comment: Maybe if you know something about the $x_i$ terms, otherwise probably not.

Comment: @BennettGardiner The actual question is a fourth degree polynomial whose roots are x_i

Comment: @BennettGardiner So I actually know the sum and product of roots .

Comment: $S$ is an argument of the complex number $(1+ix_1)(1+ix_2)(1+ix_3)(1+ix_4)$, and if you expand this, you can use what you know about $\sum x_i$ and $\prod x_i$ to simplify it a little.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177640/prove-tanaby-frac-tan-a-tan-b-tan-y-tan-a-tan-b-tan-y1-tan-a-tan.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla So I have to use the formula 4 times ?

Comment: @HansLundmark Perfect !! Thats the fastest way . Do you mind making it the answer ?

Comment: I was thinking in the answer by robjohn, that uses the same idea that Hans Lundmark.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes . Thanks a lot .

Comment: OK, I've done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S$ is an argument of the complex number $(1+ix_1)(1+ix_2)(1+ix_3)(1+ix_4)$, and if you expand this, you can use what you know about $\sum x_i$ and $\prod x_i$ to simplify it a little.

Comment: Scrap of _a little_ in the end . It simplifies everything :)

Comment: OK, fine! I didn't actually try to finish the computation, so I didn't know how well it would work. But if you're happy, I'm happy. :-)

Comment: I wonder how this idea came to you ? Is it from expeprience ?

Comment: Yes. :-) When I see $\arctan x$, I always think of a right triangle with sides $1$ and $x$, and also of the complex number $1+ix$, since it is a basic property of complex numbers that multiplication means multiplying their absolute values and *adding* their arguments.

Comment: By the way, if one thinks about it, it's pretty clear that this approach should solve the whole problem, since if your polynomial is $p(z)=c(z-x_1)(z-x_2)(z-x_3)(z-x_4)$, then $p(i)$ equals $ci^4$ times your product!